# What's the difference between 'function fName() { }` and '$(function fName(){ })' and why does the latter work while the former doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To set the scene, I am using jQuery.  I have read in another answer that "some libraries (jQuery) use the $ as the primary base object (or function)".

That's fine, but what I'm confused about is why I could have the following and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it works
  });
});
```

But then have this and it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it doesn't work
  };
});
```

So it must be the fact that I need to create that 'base object' but I could really do with an explanation in Layman's terms because this is clearly part of the fundamentals.

The final scenario is this.  I have the `$(function showPassword() {` at the start, but then have another function inside that (`function validatePwdStrength () {`.  For the second function, I don't need the `$(` and it works.  Is that because I'd previously set this 'base object'?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it works
    function validatePwdStrength () {
      //Some code and it works
    }
  });
});
```

NOTE:  I have used the phrase 'base object' a few times based on what I've read, but I don't entirely understand what it means.  I have read about [jQuery objects](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) but that seems to suggest that although it's more convenient and there's greater compatibility doing this, it should still work without it.  So I'm missing something, or many things probably.

Comment: In your first snippet, `$(document).ready(function () {` is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it works
  });
});
```

you are — redundantly — scheduling that "showPassword" function to be executed as soon as the browser has built the DOM. It's redundant because `$(document).ready(...)` is functionally identical to `$(...)`. This this would work just as well:

```
$(function showPassword() {
  // the code
});
```

In this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it doesn't work
  };
});
```

You're merely *declaring* that "showPassword" function. If you don't call it, nothing else will. Thus in that second form, this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function showPassword () {
    //Some code and it doesn't work
  };

  showPassword(); // call the function
});
```

Comment: worth noting that the plain function declaration does _not_ require semicolons, only when you declare `var myFunc = function(){};`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>   $(function showPassword () {
>     //Some code and it works
>   });
> });
> ```

Notice that [passing functions to `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) is the same as [hooking them on-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). No reason to do it twice.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>   function showPassword () {
>     //Some code and it doesn't work
>   };
> });
> ```

You're declaring the function `showPassword`, but never calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Both define a function. One also calls a function named `$` and passes the newly created function to it as an argument.

`$` (in jQuery) does half a dozen or so different things depending on what argument you pass it. If you pass it a function, it will call that function when the DOM Ready event fires (or immediately if that event has already fired).